# Iphone sdk save drawings without whole context

Tags: ipad, ios4, mkmapview, mapkit, core-location

I want to capture screen of my view from my iPhone app. I have white background view and on that I  draw a lines on that view's layer using this method .

```
- (void)draw {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    if (self.fillColor) {
        [self.fillColor setFill];
        [self.path fill];
    }
    if (self.strokeColor) {
        [self.strokeColor setStroke];
        [self.path stroke];
    }

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}



- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code.
    for (<Drawable> d in drawables) {
        [d draw];
    }
    [delegate drawTemporary];
}
```

I have use delegate methods to draw lines on layer. 
This is the project link from where I get help for this.
https://github.com/search?q=dudel&type=Everything&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1

Now when I use the following context methods to save the drawing only I successfully save it without that white background.

```
drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

But When I use the following method of Bezier Pathe I cannot save the drawing without its white background,It saves the whole screen i.e. that drawing and its background.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
    [dudelView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    //UIImage *finishedPic = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

So can anybody help me how can I save the drawing only here in this app.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

(You've tagged this as MapKit related, but make no mention of MapKit.)

Why don't you just split your drawing sequence into three chunks?

1. Draw your paths into an image context and get a UIImage, as you described.
2. Draw a background color.
3. Draw the UIImage.

Then you can use the UIImage for your "screenshot" as well.

I should also note that if the *only* thing you don't want in your captured UIImage is the background color, you are better off creating a UIImageView, setting its background color (`-setBackgroundColor:`), and setting its image to be your UIImage.

UIImageView internally has a number of optimizations that allow it to display graphics with much higher performance than you can get with a custom `-drawRect:` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just save the drawables array? Those are all the drawings without the underlying image :)